# Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope' while using std::thread

Tags: web-worker, emscripten, webassembly

I am trying to use the std::thread.

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome WASM!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Main thread=" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    auto a2 = std::thread([](){
        std::cout << "Worker thread=" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        unsigned int i = 0; 
        while (i < 100) {
            std::cout << i++ << '\n';
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        }
    });

    a2.detach();
}
```

Compilation:

```
emcc -O2 -std=c++17 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -o build\main.js main.cpp
```

This command generates the **main.js, main.worker.js and main.wasm**.
my HTML uses the main.js

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

But I am getting the error in main.worker.js:

[image: chrome dev tool screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Solution reference: https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/WebAssembly.html#web-server-setup

I have found the solution. The problem was with the web server that I was using to serve the files (HTML/js/wasm).
Earlier I was running the by the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` 
This was serving all the files (js/wasm) via MIME type "**text/plain**" and the Chrome browser was simply rejecting it (we can see it in dev tools screenshot). Chrome was expecting **application/wasm** and **application/javascript** MIME types for wasm and js files.

As suggested by one of my StackOverflow friends, I now use a web server that serves the WASM files with **application/wasm** and JS files with **application/javascript** MIME types. Now all the errors have gone. I can use both std::thread and std::async without any issue.

***server.py***

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

class Handler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler): pass

Handler.extensions_map['.wasm'] = 'application/wasm'
Handler.extensions_map['.js'] = 'application/javascript'

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome WASM!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Main thread=" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    auto f = std::thread([](){
        std::cout << "Worker thread=" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        unsigned int i = 0; 
        while (i < 100) {
            std::cout << i++ << '\n';
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        }
    });

    f.detach();
}
```

**Compilation command**

```
emcc -std=c++17 --bind  -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=2 -s PROXY_TO_PTHREAD=1 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=1073741824 -o build\main.js main.cpp -s ASSERTIONS=1
```

Here's a version of server.py that works with Python 3 (tested with Python 3.7.4):

**server_python3.py**

```
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver

PORT = 8080

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.extensions_map['.wasm'] = 'application/wasm'
Handler.extensions_map['.js'] = 'application/javascript'

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print("serving at port",PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```