# Web Worker, importScripts() MIME type

Tags: web-worker

I'm doing a website, which I want to the client do a heavy task client side.
I'm using flask and a web worker, to do that in the background, which is what I need. But I need to that web worker implement another javascript file.

I'm trying to use the method 'importScripts', but I get these errors on de console:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://192.168.1.77:5000/static/SHA.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable.
(anonymous) @ worker.js:8
worker.js:8 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://192.168.1.77:5000/static/SHA.js' failed to load.
at http://192.168.1.77:5000/static/worker.js:8:10
```

I already tried a couple of things to solve this, but I end always in this error. If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful. Thanks

I'm using Chrome no Windows.
On Firefox I get a similar error:

```
NetworkError: WorkerGlobalScope.importScripts: Failed to load worker script at ../static/SHA.js (nsresult = 0x804b001d)
```

Comment: Does your file really exists at this address? Sounds like a basic 404 from here.

Comment: Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445885/failed-to-execute-importscripts-on-workerglobalscope-while-using-stdthread => essentially, check the mime type in the network tab to ensure it's javascript